# How to use same variable name for different classes

Tags: java, oop

I'm trying to use a variable to instantiate different classes.
For example:

```
Object blah;
class1 ex1;
class2 ex2;

public void test(int i){
    if(i == 1){
        blah = new class1();
    } else {
        blah = new class2();
    }
}
```

How would I go about doing this in java?

**Edit 1:**
Sorry guys, let me try to get more specific now.

Let's say I have three classes: A, B and C.

A is where my main is and uses B. B uses C.

The issue is this:

```
public class B1{
    C instanceC;

    public B1(){
    instanceC = new C();
    //uses a method of instanceC.
    }
}
public class B2{
    C instanceC;

    public C(){
    instanceC = new C();
    //uses a method of instanceC.
    }
}
```

and then in A:

```
public class A implements MouseListener{
    Object blah;
    B1 instanceB1;
    B2 instanceB2;

    public void test(int i){
        if(i == 1){
            blah = new B1();
        } else {
            blah = new B2();
        }
    }
//I left the other mouseListener methods blank
    public void mouseReleased(int i){
        blah.instanceC.someMethod();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        A instanceA = new A();
        A.test(1);
    }
}
```

**Edit 2:** When I try to use instanceC.someMethod() or instanceC.someVariable it gives me a null pointer exception.

I hope this was clear enough. If it's confusing please let me know and I'll see if I can simplify it further. Thanks to the people who have helped already!

Comment: The intent behind that code should work, but it's probably not a good idea.

Comment: How "different" are these classes? If their common base class is indeed `Object`, you have a design problem imho

Comment: You could look into Scala's case classes but I guess it's unrelated. Just want to throw it out there.

Comment: @fge: for some scenario like XML/JSON serialization "Object" is the only common type but you may want to instantiate different types depending on the data.

Comment: @Recur: what you try to do is similar to what the factory pattern normalizes.

Answer (score 5):

If `blah` is declared as `Object`, that would work (other than that you're using `new` with instances rather than classes) — but it would be awkward to use any methods or properties on it that aren't on `Object`.

The usual way to do this is via *interfaces*. The interface defines the common characteristics of `class1` and `class2`, and then you declare `blah` using the interface. Then you can easily make the concrete class one or the other, and have access to the common characteristics.

E.g.:

```
interface Foo {
    void someCommonMethod();
}

class Class1 implements Foo {
    void someCommonMethod() {
        // implementation
    }
}

class Class2 implements Foo {
    void someCommonMethod() {
        // implementation
    }
}

public void test(int i){
    if(i == 1){
        blah = new Class1();
    } else {
        blah = new Class2();
    }

    // ...use `someCommonMethod` on `blah`...
}
```

Comment: Hey T.J. thanks for the quick reply and suggestion. I've clarified my situation further in the hopes that everyone can get a better understanding of my situation.

Comment: @Recur: Still the same answer. Have an interface that both `B1.C` and `B2.C` implement, and use the interface to declare `instanceC`.

Answer (score 0):

Your code never compiles.

- What are B1 and B2? What is `C()` in them, the signature is like a constructor, but the name is not. If it is not a constructor then how you assure that the `instanceC` is initialized within `B1` and `B2`?
- What is `A instanceA = new instanceA();`? Shall it be `A instanceA = new A();`? and then calling `instanceA.test()`?

If my assumptions are correct, then you are trying to access `instanceC` of two different objects, the question is, "Is it always named instanceC?", if that's the case use reflection, and look for the field by name.

If you want to iterate over all fields of the classes and do something with them, again use reflection and iterate over fields, check for their type and for proper field types invoke the method.

Comment: Yep it's always named instanceC. I'll take a look at reflection then. Thanks.